# pyspark - is it possible to filter dataframe with multiple expression in lambda function

Tags: pyspark

I have below code which is to return rows contains empty or null value on any column.

```
cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H","I"]
expr = exists(array(*cols), lambda x: (x.isNull() or x==""))
df_filter = df.filter(expr).display()
```

but got below error

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Question:
how to filter dataframe with multiple expressions in lambda fuction.

Comment: Your function is almost correct.  You just need to use `|` for "or" and wrap `x == ""` because `|` has a higher precedence. `lambda x: (x.isNull() | (x==""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cols = ["A",  "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H","I"]

df.show()

+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID|Company_Id|      A|      B|value-3|      D|
+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1A|   3412asd|Approve|   null|   null|       |
| 2B|   2345tyu|Approve|Approve|   null|   null|
| 3C|   9800bvd|Approve|   null|Approve|Approve|
+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

code

```
  (df.withColumn('c',array_intersect(transform(array(*[c for x in cols if (c:=str(x))in (df.columns) ]), lambda x: coalesce(x, lit('xx'))),array(lit('xx'), lit(''))))
 .where(size(col('c'))!=0)

).show(truncate=False)
```

outcome

```
+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+----+----+
|ID |Company_Id|A      |B      |value-3|D   |c   |
+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+----+----+
|1A |3412asd   |Approve|null   |null   |    |[]  |
|2B |2345tyu   |Approve|Approve|null   |null|[xx]|
+---+----------+-------+-------+-------+----+----+
```

How it works

1. `array(*[c for x in cols if (c:=str(x))in (df.columns) ])`

using walrus operator, it creates an array of all columns in cols

2. `transform(array(*[c for x in cols if (c:=str(x))in (df.columns) ]), lambda x: coalesce(x, lit('xx')))`

Fills nulls in 1 above with string `xx`

3. `array_intersect(transform(array(*[c for x in cols if (c:=str(x))in (df.columns) ]), lambda x: coalesce(x, lit('xx'))),array(lit('xx'), lit('')))`

Intersects outcome of 2 above with an ['xx','']

4. filters out rows that come out of operation 3 that has arrays with elements

   .where(size(col('c'))!=0)

Comment: Are you able to give me an upvote. I gave you one